# How do I call and API (nodejs) which returns a CSV file, from a ionic application

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, ionic4

I have tried a method like this.. but i don't get anything back, i think it is expected a json object rather than a csv file..

```
private httpGet(url: string, token: any, callback: any) {
    this.http.get(url, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',// 'attachment/csv',
        'Authorization': token
      })
    }).subscribe(res => {
      callback(res);
    });
  }
```

THe node js server endpoint (in express) has the following return code..

```
try {
            const csv = parse(newArray, opts);
            res.attachment("myfile_" + dtStart + "_to_" + dtEnd + ".csv");
            console.log("about to send csv");
            res.status(200).json(newArray);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('export error' + e);
            res.status(401).send("<h5>There was an error proecessing the report </h5><br>" + e);
        }
```

**Why can't i just call the endpoint directly using window.open(URL). Because i only want authorized users to call it..**

Answer (score 1):

1.The reason you cannot do a window.open Url because it is not a file path rather an endpoint hence if you had the absolute path on the server of a file where it is stored it would work.

2.For this you would be receiving a blob hence you can look for  **Papa Parse** package to import and also export CSV data with Ionic.

Try the **following code :**

```js
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import * as papa from 'papaparse';
     this.http.get('assets/dummyData.csv')
          .subscribe(
          (res) =>{
    
        let csvData = res['_body'] || '';
        let parsedData = papa.parse(csvData).data;
        this.headerRow = parsedData[0];
     
        parsedData.splice(0, 1);
        this.csvData = parsedData;
     
    
    let csv = papa.unparse({
          fields: this.headerRow,
          data: this.csvData
        });
     
        // Dummy implementation for Desktop download purpose
        var blob = new Blob([csv]);
        var a = window.document.createElement("a");
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = "newdata.csv";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
    
    },
    
          err => console.log(err) // this.handleError(err)
          );
```

Comment: ok thanks - i think it is safer to get the json object from the api, then convert it to a csv in the client